# Overriding the << method for instance variables

Tags: ruby

Let's suppose I have this class:

```rb
class Example
  attr_accessor :numbers

  def initialize(numbers = [])
    @numbers = numbers
  end

  private

  def validate!(number)
    number >= 0 || raise(ArgumentError)
  end
end
```

I would like to run the `#validate!` on any new number before pushing it into the `numbers`:

```rb
example = Example.new([1, 2, 3])
example.numbers # [1, 2, 3]
example.numbers << 4
example.numbers # [1, 2, 3, 4]
example.numbers << -1 # raise ArgumentError
```

Below is the best I can do but I'm really not sure about it.

Plus it works only on `<<`, not on `push`. I could add it but there is risk of infinite loop...).

Is there a more "regular" way to do it? I couldn't find any official process for that.

```rb
class Example
  attr_accessor :numbers

  def initialize(numbers = [])
    @numbers = numbers
    bind = self # so the instance is usable inside the singleton block
    @numbers.singleton_class.send(:define_method, :<<) do |value|
      # here, self refers to the @numbers array, so use bind to refer to the instance
      bind.send(:validate!, value)
      push(value)
    end
  end

  private

  def validate!(number)
    number >= 0 || raise(ArgumentError)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programming is a lot like real life: it is not a good idea to just run around and let strangers touch your private parts.

You are solving the wrong problem. You are trying to regulate what strangers can do when they play with your private parts, but instead you simply shouldn't let them touch your privates in the first place.

```ruby
class Example
  def initialize(numbers = [])
    @numbers = numbers.clone
  end

  def numbers
    @numbers.clone.freeze
  end

  def <<(number)
    validate(number)
    @numbers << number
    self
  end

  private

  def validate(number)
    raise ArgumentError, "number must be non-negative, but is #{number}" unless number >= 0
  end
end

example = Example.new([1, 2, 3])
example.numbers # [1, 2, 3]
example << 4
example.numbers # [1, 2, 3, 4]
example << -1 # raise ArgumentError
```

Let's look at all the changes I made one-by-one.

## `clone`ing the initializer argument

You are taking a mutable object (an array) from an untrusted source (the caller). You should make sure that the caller cannot do anything "sneaky". In your first code, I can do this:

```ruby
ary = [1, 2, 3]
example = Example.new(ary)

ary << -1
```

Since you simply took *my* array I handed you, I can still do to the array anything I want!

And even in the hardened version, I can do this:

```ruby
ary = [1, 2, 3]
example = Example.new(ary)

class << ary
  remove_method :<<
end

ary << -1
```

Or, I can `freeze` the array before I hand it to you, which makes it impossible to add a singleton method to it.

Even *without* the safety aspects, you should *still* do this, because you violate another real-life rule: Don't play with other people's toys! I am handing you *my* array, and then you mutate it. In the real world, that would be considered rude. In programming, it is *surprising*, and surprises breed bugs.

## `clone`ing in the getter

This goes to the heart of the matter: the `@numbers` array is my private internal state. I should *never* hand that to strangers. If you don't hand the `@numbers` array out, then none of the problems you are protecting against can even occur.

You are trying to protect against strangers mutating your internal state, and the solution to that is simple: don't give strangers your internal state!

The `freeze` is technically not necessary, but I like it to make clear to the caller that this is just a view into the state of the `example` object, and they are only allowed to view what I want them to.

And again, even *without* the safety aspects, this would still be a bad idea: by exposing your internal implementation to clients, you can no longer change the internal implementation without breaking clients. If you change the array to a linked list, your clients are going to break, because they are used to getting an array that you can randomly index, but you can't randomly index a linked list, you always have to traverse it from the front.

The example is unfortunately too small and simple to judge that, but I would even question why you are handing out arrays in the first place. What do the clients want to do with those numbers? Maybe it is enough for them to just iterate over them, in which case you don't need to give them a whole array, just an iterator:

```ruby
class Example
  def each(...)
    return enum_for(__callee__) unless block_given?
    @numbers.each(...)
    self
  end
end
```

If the caller wants an array, they can still easily get one by calling `to_a` on the `Enumerator`.

Note that I return `self`. This has two reasons:

1. It is simply the contract of `each`. Every other object in Ruby that implements `each` returns `self`. If this were Java, this would be part of the `Iterable` interface.
2. I would actually accidentally leak the internal state that I work so hard to protect! As I just wrote: every implementation of `each` returns `self`, so what does `@numbers.each` return? It returns `@numbers`, which means my whole `Example#each` method returns `@numbers` which is exactly the thing I am trying to hide!

## Implement `<<` myself

Instead of handing out my internal state and have the *caller* append to it, *I* control what happens with my internal state. I implement my *own* version of `<<` in which I can check for whatever I want and make sure no invariants of my object are violated.

Note that I return `self`. This has two reasons:

1. It is simply the contract of `<<`. Every other object in Ruby that implements `<<` returns `self`. If this were Java, this would be part of the `Appendable` interface.
2. I would actually accidentally leak the internal state that I work so hard to protect! As I just wrote: every implementation of `<<` returns `self`, so what does `@numbers << number` return? It returns `@numbers`, which means my whole `Example#<<` method returns `@numbers` which is exactly the thing I am trying to hide!

## Drop the bang

In Ruby, method names that end with a bang mean "This method is more surprising than its non-bang counterpart". In your case, there *is no* non-bang counterpart, so the method shouldn't have a bang.

## Don't abuse boolean operators for control flow

… or at least if you do, use the keyword versions (`and` / `or`) instead of the symbolic ones (`&&` / `||`).

But really, you should void it altogether. `do or die` is idiomatic in Perl, but not in Ruby.

Technically, I have changed the return value of your method: it used to return `true` for a valid value, now it returns `nil`. But you ignore its return value anyway, so it doesn't matter.

`validate` is probably not a good name for the method, though. I would expect a method named `validate` to return a boolean result, not raise an exception.

## An exceptional message

You should add messages to your exceptions that tell the programmer what went wrong. Another possibility is to create more specific exceptions, e.g.

```ruby
class NegativeNumberError < ArgumentError; end
```

But that would be overkill in this case. In general, if you expect *code* to "read" your exception, create a new class, if you expect *humans* to read your exception, then a message is enough.

## Encapsulation, Data Abstraction, Information Hiding

Those are three subtly different but related concepts, and they are among the most important concepts in programming. We *always* want *hide* our internal state and *encapsulate* it behind methods that we control.

## Encapsulation to the max

Some people (including myself) don't particularly like even the object itself playing with its internal state. Personally, I even encapsulate private instance variables that are never exposed behind getters and setters. The reason is that this makes the class easier to subclass: you can override and specialize methods, but not instance variables. So, if I use the instance variable directly, a subclass cannot "hook" into those accesses.

Whereas if I use getter and setter methods, the subclass can override those (or only one of those).

Note: the example is too small and simple, so I had some real trouble coming up with a good name (there is not enough in the example to understand how the variable is used and what it means), so eventually, I just gave up, but you will see what I mean about using getters and setters:

```ruby
class Example
  class NegativeNumberError < ArgumentError; end

  def initialize(numbers = [])
    self.numbers_backing = numbers.clone
  end

  def each(...)
    return enum_for(__callee__) unless block_given?
    numbers_backing.each(...)
    self
  end

  def <<(number)
    validate(number)
    numbers_backing << number
    self
  end

  private

  attr_accessor :numbers_backing

  def validate(number)
    raise NegativeNumberError unless number >= 0
  end
end

example = Example.new([1, 2, 3])
example.each.to_a # [1, 2, 3]
example << 4
example.each.to_a # [1, 2, 3, 4]
example << -1 # raise NegativeNumberError
```

Comment: I will read this several times, so many thing to keep in mind here :)
Sorry if the example is not really expressive. I'm working on a tool (more of a study  for now) that dynamically creates class properties and `#initialize` method, so `numbers` is an example but it is a consequence that I cannot control. Plus, they could be more than one array so `def <<(number)` wouldn't work since I wouldn't know in which array to push the value. But You answer helped me to understand that all my problem comes from the accessor thing. I think I will able to fix it :)

Comment: I've changed my code so now the "stranger" can: "get" the variable value (in fact, a frozen clone of it), "set" the variable value (through a dedicated `foo=(value)` that validates it). But the "stranger" cannot "mutate" a variable: i.e. pushing a value inside an array (which is a clone of the instance variable) raises a `FrozenError`.