# Instance Variable changed unintentionally by a different class

Tags: ruby

I'm currently learning the basics of Ruby and OOP in general. From what I've read so far, I can use attr_reader to grab the value of an instance variable but not give it access to be overwritten. However, given the code block below, the end result is not what I intended and the instance variable was completely changed from outside of the class. What would be the best way where I can simply read the value and return the intended changes into another variable instead of overwriting the instance variable itself?

```
class X
  def initialize
    @y = [1,2,3,4]
  end
  attr_reader :y
end

class Z
  def initialize
  end
  def self.change(arr)
    arr[1] = 0
    arr[2] = 0
    return arr
  end
end

x = X.new
z = Z.change(x.y)
p z
p x.y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using `clone`: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Object.html#method-i-clone

> Produces a shallow copy of obj—the instance variables of obj are copied, but not the objects they reference.

```rb
class X
  def initialize
    @y = [1,2,3,4]
  end
  attr_reader :y
end

class Z
  def self.change(arr)
    arr2 = arr.clone
    arr2[1] = 0
    arr2[2] = 0
    return arr2
  end
end

x = X.new
z = Z.change(x.y)
p z
p x.y
```

Comment: This requires each caller to pay attention not to overwrite the data. It might be better if `X` would protect / encapsulate its data properly in a way that prevents such change.

Answer (score 2):

> From what I've read so far, I can use `attr_reader` to grab the value of an instance variable but not give it access to be overwritten.

Yes and no.

`attr_reader :y` creates a so-called *getter* which is equivalent to:

```
def y
  @y
end
```

`attr_writer :y` creates the corresponding *setter*:

```
def y=(value)
  @y = value
end
```

And `attr_accessor` creates both.

The getter allows you to conveniently access `@y` from the outside. The setter allows you to *re-assign* `@y`.

But even with just a getter, you can still *send messages* to the object. And if the object is *mutable*, like your array, you can modify it that way:

```
x = X.new
x.y #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
x.y.push(5)
x.y #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

In the above example, `@y` is not re-assigned, it still refers the same object. But the message [`push`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#push-method) caused the object to change itself.

> What would be the best way where I can simply read the value [...]

There are several options. If you want to prevent modification form the outside, you could return a copy of the original array:

```
class X
  def initialize
    @y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
  end

  def y
    @y.dup
  end
end
```

[`dup`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Object.html#dup-method) creates a shallow copy of the array and returns it. "shallow" means that a new array is created containing the same elements. Any modification from the outside to the array will only affect the copy.

But you could still modify its elements (via messages) and that change would be reflected by both, original and copy.

Fortunately, your array contains integers which are *immutable*.

Answer (score 1):

> However, given the code block below, the end result is not what I intended and the instance variable was completely changed from outside of the class.

No, it wasn't. The *object* that the instance variable *references* was changed. That is to be expected: arrays can be changed, and you handed the caller an array, so the caller can obviously change the array.

But the instance variable was not changed: it still points to the exact same object as before.

My boss and my mother call me by different names. But if I shave my beard, both of them will see my clean-shaven face.

Understanding the difference between a *thing* and the *name* of the thing is *fundamental* in programming.

> What would be the best way where I can simply read the value and return the intended changes into another variable instead of overwriting the instance variable itself?

The best way is to not expose internal representation in the first place. It's not quite clear from your question how a client is expected to use `X` (the naming is pretty terrible). So, for example, if clients are expected to iterate over the contents of `@y`, then you offer them a way to do exactly that and *only* that.

```ruby
class X
  def initialize
    self.y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
  end

  def each_y(...)
    return enum_for(__callee__) unless block_given?
    y.each(...)
    self
  end

  private attr_accessor :y
end
```

See [Overriding the << method for instance variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64379609/2988) for another example of the same problem and how to solve it.

Comment: Good explanation, as always :-) The private accessors are a nice touch, but for someone _"learning the basics of Ruby"_ it might be more helpful to keep the example as simple and as explicit as possible, i.e. using `@y` directly, writing out the `...` parts and showing how `each_y` can be called.